# OnSlideShowChangePage doesn't run when Page Changed

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a countdown in Visual Basic for my PowerPoint presentation. This worked absolutely fine. I need the macro to start when The slide changes. The slide has to change after 20 seconds. This also works. But when I change the slide programmatically the method OnSlideShowChangedPage doesn't run. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?
This is my code:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

MsgBox "Fired"

Dim pos As Integer
pos = Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition

Dim time As Date
time = Now()
    
Dim count As Integer
count = 20
    
time = DateAdd("s", count, time)
    
Do Until time < Now()
    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.Slides(pos).Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "hh:mm:ss")
Loop

ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are changing the slide with some code, could you not simply also call OnSlideShowPageChange() with the same code at the same time?

Comment: No. That doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean? When you say you are changing the slide programmatically, i assume you mean with some vba code? Can you call OnSlideShowPageChange() just after this code? Are you saying that if you call OnSlideShowPageChange() that it does nothing?

Comment: garbb is on the right path. Just add the code you want to run after ```ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next```. No need  for an event, which is watching your manual actions in PowerPoint.